# Remove ubuntu-session

Tags: unity, dpkg

I wanted to remove unity-settings-daemon because thats the only unity-package I have it besides unity-greeter. I run a gnome-shell, hence do not need unity.
However, when I try to remove unity-settings-daemon, dpkg would also like to remove ubuntu-session. Is it safe to do it, or would I break my display manager or something else?

```
dpkg -L ubuntu-session 

/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/gnome-session
/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions
/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-session
/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-session/copyright
/usr/share/xsessions
/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop
/usr/share/lightdm
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-session/README
/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-session/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-session/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-session/NEWS.gz
```

Also, is there a way to show which files would be removed when I do a sudo apt-get remove --dry-run PackageName ? 
At the moment, I see which packages would be removed, but not which files would be removed.

Comment: So, in short, you only want to have gnome desktop, correct ?

Comment: yes, I want to have gnome-desktop-environment only.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully removed unity completely from my system and just have the gnome-desktop-environment with gdm as my default display manager. I did not have to install any packages such as ubuntu-desktop or gnome-ubuntu-desktop for not breaking any dependacies.

```
dpkg -L ubuntu-session
```

shows that gnome-session is a part of the package, but actually it is not. Only by explicitly removing gnome-session via sudo apt-get remove gnome-session, the gnome-session would be removed, otherwise not.
Finally, I have a poor gnome desktop environment without any unity parasites :)

Answer (score 0):

You can install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` metapackage and remove `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage. Some time ago I tested this approach in Ubuntu Virtual Machine, and it has proven to work appropriately. Use the following steps to do that:

1. Go to TTY1 via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> keyboard shortcut. Login
2. Run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`. The command will install complete set of packages used in [Ubuntu Gnome](https://ubuntugnome.org/) edition. The boot up screen and various configurations will be altered to suit the Ubuntu Gnome. Login screen should be set to `gdm` , but you can alternatively keep `lightdm` without penalty to the user experience.
3. Once it is installed , reboot to ensure changes have taken effect. If you are satisfied with the result, from TTY1 (same as in step #1 ) run `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop`. If you wish to keep unity as backup desktop environment, skip this step.

**Sidenote:** for best results run `sudo apt-get update` prior to installing the Ubuntu Gnome metapackage

Comment: Thanks for your reply and time, but it still does not answer my question. If removing unity-settings-daemon break my display manager? And also a second question, if there is any way, that I can know, which files would be explicitly removed ( using a dry-run method ) when a paket is attempted to be removed.

Comment: Just saw, that ubuntu-desktop on my system is already removed.

Comment: OK, would have been nice if that info was provided earlier in the question.  So now you can try to remove `unity-settings-daemon`  manually via `sudo apt-get --remove unity-settings-daemon`. It probably will remove some dependencies as well, which is why it is important that you have `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` installed to keep the system usable